# How can you add Symfony form fields based on failed validation?

Tags: php, symfony1, symfony-forms, symfony-1.4

Basically, my model requires that an object is tied to a physical location. For this I'm pulling locations from an API via AJAX using keywords entered by a user in a text field, jQuery autocomplete is setup to set a hidden field to a unique ID when the user selects a valid location recommended to them.

This is all fine, assuming the user has JavaScript and clicks a location.

I need to implement a fallback, i.e. for whatever reason, if the form is submitted without the hidden field having a value, the form should use whatever is in the visible to query the API and present a select box for users to choose a value from.

I know roughly the code I need to add, but I'm lost as to where to bind it in. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Essentially you have to create a custome widget and use it in place of the locations form field. You can then add you javascript to the widgets rendering. If you extend sfWidgetChoice or the doctrine equivalent it will default to a select box. Then if js is enabled your widget's js will rewrite the field to an auto complete.

Have a look at the [sfFormExtraPlugin](http://www.symfony-project.org/plugins/sfFormExtraPlugin) for some great examples of how to do this.

Comment: I'm not sure you read my question fully, I've already done all of what you suggested, it's moving on from that that I am now struggling with.

Comment: What I'm saying is. Your widget should by default be the fallback element. Then if and only if js (or whatever) is enabled should the element become an autocomplete. It's called progressive enhancement http://www.alistapart.com/articles/understandingprogressiveenhancement/

Comment: Or you could use graceful degradation (http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/graceful-degradation-progressive-enhance/) which says make it the best it can be by default (i.e. autocomplete) then have it fall back if features aren't supported (i.e. javascript). Either way, all this should be part of your widget which is why I suggested you look at the sfFormExtraPlugin, it's a great example of how to use progressive enhancement in your widgets.

Comment: Only just seen your edit, sfWidgetFormJQueryAutocompleter of sfFormExtraPlugin looks helpful- ta.

Comment: The reason there are two fields is because the user should never have to see an ID, it means nothing to them- I'm questioning whether this is feasible via this widget unless it accommodates for that. Still looking.

Comment: Yes it is. Essentially you widget renders two fields. One is hidden (this is the field whose values is used) and one that is visible (called a place holder). This place holder should be created via your widgets javascript at runtime. This same javascript changes your main field to a hidden input type. This makes use of progressive enhancement. I believe the jQueryDateWidget in the sfFormExtraPlugin does just that.